# How do I Authenticate with Google on a Blazor page

Tags: c#, blazor, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to Authorise an action with google, in this case listing the YouTube Videos from that google account on a Blazor page.
If I try this code it just throws an error

> Error: System.InvalidOperationException: OnStarting cannot be set because the response has already started.

On that line:

```
   @inject IGoogleAuthProvider auth
              
   <h3>YoutubeTest</h3>
   <button @onclick="Test ">load</button>
       
   @code {
       [GoogleScopedAuthorize( new[] { YouTubeService.ScopeConstants.YoutubeReadonly } )]
       private async void Test()
       {
>>>        GoogleCredential cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
           //[...]
       }
   }
```

I got it kind of working from the sample from the Google Api .NET samples but it is a Controller and I don't really know what to do with those.

```
[Route( "api/[controller]" )]
[ApiController]
public class YoutubeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet( "[action]" )]
    [GoogleScopedAuthorize( new[] { YouTubeService.ScopeConstants.YoutubeReadonly } )]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoadYtVideos( [FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth , string path )
    {
        GoogleCredential cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();

        var service = new YouTubeService( new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = cred , ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
        } );

        var channelListRequest = service.Channels.List( "contentDetails" );
        channelListRequest.Mine = true;
        ChannelListResponse channelListResponse = await channelListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
    }
}
```

**Edit 1**

In the end I went with a hacky version that probably has some problems but since its only me whos gonna be able to use it anyways I thought I'd try it.

Basically I added a Singleton that has a `ICredential` stored and in my controller I set that to the credential I got in the controller.
Then I do a Redirect back to the blazor (.razor) page and in there I can use the service to access the Credentials that I stored in the Singleton.

It's probably not a good way of doing it, but it works for me for now and maybe it can help someone else too.

Comment: The google .net client library doesnt fully support blazor.  Have a look at this.  https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/2017#issuecomment-1034970872

Comment: @DaImTo Ok thats unfortunate. Do You by any chance know how to navigate from for example that controller code up there to a Blazor page (.razor)?

Comment: The asp.net sample its not going to be compatible with blazor